# Rails upload form with carrierwave and polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, carrierwave, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to wrap my head around using polymorphic associations to make file management less repetitive in a simple rails app.  I'm using carrierwave to handle the file uploading.  Here's what I have so far:

**app/uploaders/file_uploader.rb**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

**app/models/attachment.rb**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**app/models/photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :caption, :attachment
  has_one :attachment, as: :attachable
end
```

I can handle this fine in the rails console:

```
$ rails console
> photo = Photo.new
> attachment = Attachment.new
> attachment.file = File.open('tmp/demo.png')
> photo.attachment = attachment
> photo.save
> photo.attachment
=> #<Attachment id: 3, file: "demo.png", attachable_id: 5, attachable_type: "Photo", created_at: "2013-04-13 16:56:31", updated_at: "2013-04-13 16:56:31">
```

So my problem is really in the photos controller:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PhotosController#create
Attachment(#70310274945400) expected, got ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#70310271741380)`
```

Any help on this is hugely appreciated.  I might not have the greatest grasp of polymorphic associations.

UPDATE

Taking @manoj's suggestion, I edited the photo form to nest the attachment:

```
<%= f.fields_for :attachment do |attachment_f| %>
    <%= attachment_f.file_field :file %>
<% end %>
```

I'm now getting this error when I attempt to submit the form:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Attachment(#70135925415240) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70135923190420)):
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:43:in 'new'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:43:in 'create'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post params should be something like this

```
params => { "photo" => 
               { :attachment_attribute => 
                  {:file => ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile}
               }
          }
```

but your post param most probably is

```
params => { "photo" => { :attachment => ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile}}
```

Your view should contain fields_for to handle the nesting in models. You have to create a file field for the attribute "file" of the Attachment model

```
<%=form_for @photo do |photo_f|%>
  ....
  <%=photo_f.fields_for :attachment do |attachment_f|%>
     <%= attachment_f.file_field :file%>
  <%end%>
  ....
<%end%>
```

UPDATE

```
<%=photo_f.fields_for :attachment_attributes do |attachment_f|%>
```

And in the photo model add these,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachment
attr_accessible ..., :attachment_attributes
```

Comment: thanks for the help @manoj.  I think I'm getting closer but I'm getting the above error (see update to my question)

Comment: What helped me was the ANAF stuff. Thanks for jogging my memory!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%=form_for @photo do |photo_f|%>
 ....
 <%=photo_f.fields_for :attachment_attributes do |attachment_f|%>
  <%= attachment_f.file_field :file %>
 <%end%>
 ....
<%end%>
```